# build number in pom is empty

Tags: maven, build-process, pom.xml, manifest.mf

I am trying to create a manifest entry "Build" whose value is build number. The generated buildNumber from the following POM is empty and I cannot figure out why. All the other fields in the manifest.mf file are correct.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.edvs</groupId>
<artifactId>EDVSTestJar1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>EDVSTestJar1</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://127.0.0.1/dummy</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://127.0.0.1/dummy</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
    <url>http://127.0.0.1/dummy</url>
</scm>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <maven.build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</maven.build.timestamp>
    <jar.finalName>EDVSTestJar1</jar.finalName>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Dependency to EDVSCommon -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.edvs</groupId>
        <artifactId>EDVSCommon</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>true</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>

                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.edvs.main.TestIt</mainClass>
                        <classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
                        <customClasspathLayout>WEB-INF/lib/${artifact.groupIdPath}/${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Date>${maven.build.timestamp}</Date>
                        <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                        <Build>${buildNumber}</Build>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <connectionType>developerConnection</connectionType>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: the buildnumber-maven-plugin plugin will try to use the defined scm sections info, which apparentely are dummy data, it might be related to that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It got me thinking. I do not have a real SVN (source code management) so Maven does not have any real place to look for the build number. Once I start to use source code management I believe the problem will go away. I hope.